# Creating and Calculating Fields in Access

Tags: database, ms-access, search

I've been working on an exercise for school that should have been rather simple. For some reason I cant quite figure out where I went wrong. I have been at it awhile so I may be overlooking something simple. I have some experience with data bases and actually implemented sqlite earlier today in an app but access is throwing me for a loop ! Any help is much appreciated.

***Directions:***

create a relationship between the tblEmployee table and the tblDepartment table as well as between the tblEmployee and the tblSale table. Be sure to enforce referential integrity in both relationships.
Create a query in Design view using the tblEmployee, tblProduct, tblSale, and tblSaleDetail tables. Add the First, Last, and Active? fields (in that order) to the query. Make the following changes to the query:
Display only active employees.
In the first empty column, calculate a new field, Total Sales (UnitPrice * Quantity) for each active employee.
Only display employees with more that than $300.00 in Total Sales.
Calculate a new field, Total Revenue (Total Sales – (Coupon * Quantity)) for each active employee.
Sum the UnitPrice, Quantity, Coupon, Total Sales, and Total Revenue fields.
Show First, Last, Total Sales, and Total Revenue in the query results.

***Access Setup***

[image]

***When I run the query***

[image]

Why is Total Sales not populated from that equation ?

Also, im a little unclear on where to add the > 300.00 to filter on employee sales.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL statement that you created in the design view? Preferably a clean-up version of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't the `total sales` column, it is that you refer to a calculated field `total sales` when you create a column called `total revenue`.

`Total Sales` is only calculated once the query has been run, but `total revenue` wants to know what the value is before the query is run.

A workaround for this is to use the same calculation:

```
 total revenue: ([Quantity]*[UnitPrice])-([coupon]*[quantity])
```

Another workaround is to create a query that calculates `total sales`. You can then insert that query into this one and use it as a subquery.

> As for the ">300 for employee sales". I think the following **may** work:

I assume this is a monetary value by the 2 decimal places and not a 'number of sales' value. Therefore, I would add a new column.

`SumOfSales: sum([tblSales].[quantity]*[tblSales].[UnitPrice])`

- Criteria: >300.00
- Show: *unticked*

Comment: You made complete sense and made me feel dumb. Thanks a million !